# A function $g : \{0,1\}^m \to \{0,1\}^{4m}$ such that the “circular discrepancy” between $g(x_1)$ and $g(x_2)$ is $\geq m$ for any $x_1 \neq x_2$

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, combinatorics-on-words

In this question, the term “word” implies a binary word, i.e. a sequence of bits.

Let $W(x)$ denote the number of non-zero bits in a word $x$.

Assuming that $x$ is an $s$-bit word and $0 \le k < s$, let $R^k(x)$ denote the result of the left bitwise rotation (i.e. the left [circular shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift)) of $x$ by $k$ bits. For example, if $x = 0100110001110000$, then $s = 16$ and $$\begin{array}{l}
R^0(x) = x = {\text{0100110001110000}},\\
R^1(x) = {\text{1001100011100000}},\\
R^2(x) = {\text{0011000111000001}},\\
 \ldots \\
R^{15}(x) = {\text{0010011000111000}}.
\end{array}$$

Let $x_0 \oplus x_1$ denote the result of the bitwise [“exclusive or”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operation for two words of the same length. For example, $$0100110001110000 \oplus 1010010001000010 = 1110100000110010.$$

Assuming that $x_0$ and $x_1$ are two words of length $s$, let $f(x_0, x_1)$ denote the minimal element (the smallest number) in the tuple $$\begin{array}{l}
(W(x_0 \oplus x_1),\\
W(x_0 \oplus R^1(x_1)),\\
W(x_0 \oplus R^2(x_1)),\\
\ldots \\
W(x_0 \oplus R^{s - 1}(x_1))).
\end{array}$$

I need a generalized (i.e. suitable for an *arbitrary* integer $m \geq 1$) *efficient* algorithm for an [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) function $g(x)$ that takes an $m$-bit word $x$ as the input and outputs the $4m$-bit word. The function must satisfy the following property:

> if $x_1 \neq x_2,$ then $f(g(x_1), g(x_2)) \geq m.$

Is it possible to write the algorithm for such a function?

Comment: Have you tried using a map from $2^m$-bit integers to de Bruijn sequences to build a $g$? See also perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_length_sequence#Correlation_property

Comment: I think there's a discrepancy between the title and the question. If $W(x)$ counts *non*-zero symbols (i.e. Hamming weight) then $W(x_0, x_1)$ counts *discrepancies* between $x_0$ and $x_1$, so $f(g(x_1), g(x_2)) \ge m$ means that the cross-correlation of $g(x_1)$ and $g(x_2)$ is $\le 3m$.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean in the light of @PeterTaylor's comment. There is a lot of work in this area but the distance/correlation function is crucial to the techniques used and what's known.

Comment: @PeterTaylor do you mean $W(x_0\oplus x_1)$ in your comment?

Comment: @kodlu, yes, that's my error.

Comment: How can a function from $m$-bit words to $4m$-bit words be bijective?

Comment: I think the meaning is probably one to one, didn't notice, thanks

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev, it's not stated that the codomain is *all* $4m$-bit words. My interpretation of the question is to find a clique of size $2^m$ in the graph whose vertices are $4m$-bit words and whose edges correspond to the correlation property, and to find a "nice" ranking function for the members of that clique.

Comment: If you have access to an IEEE subscription, Lempel, A., & Greenberger, H. (1974). Families of sequences with optimal Hamming-correlation properties. IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, 20(1), 90-94 looks relevant.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: It does not make sense to say that a function is bijective without specifying its range. My understanding is that the OP meant injective rather than bijective function. It will surely be a bijection between its domain and its range.

Comment: So, basically neither Peng-Tang (Peng D., Fan P.
Lower bounds on the hamming auto-and cross-correlations of frequency-hopping sequences
IEEE Trans. Inform. Theory, 50 (2004), pp. 2149-2154) nor Welch bounds rule out the existence of a set of vectors with the properties the OP wants. Constructing such a set analytically or constructing one that has an efficient mapping from {0,1}^m to {0,1}^4m is another matter